# Acceleration of a rotated point using rotation matrices

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, acceleration, rotation

I am trying to calculate the acceleration of a point using rotation matrices and struggle to get my head around them.

Imagine an inverted pendulum which can rotate about its x-axis but not any other axis. Lets say the y-axis points to the right, the z-axis down (towards gravity) and the x-axis into the monitor.
To calculate the acceleration of a point on that pendulum my idea was to define two frames $\mathbf{x_B}$ and $\mathbf{x_I}$ for the body and inertial frames respectively. The inertial frame is supposed to be stationary and since the body frame can rotate about the (common) x-axis the relationship is as follows:
$$\mathbf{x_I=R_xx_B}$$
where $\mathbf{R_x}$ is the rotation matrix defined by
$$\mathbf{R_x}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\0&\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$

Multiplying with $\mathbf{R_x^T}$ and differentiating with respect to time gives us
$$\mathbf{\dot x_B=\dot R_x^T x_I=\dot R_x^TR_x x_B}$$
and differentiating once more
$$\mathbf{\ddot x_B=(\ddot R_x^TR_x+\dot R_x^T \dot R_x)x_B+\dot R_x^TR_x \dot x_B}.$$

Now, what I expect to see if I calculate $\mathbf{\ddot x_B}$ is that when I choose a value for $\mathbf{x_B}$, like for example $\mathbf{x_B=}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-z\end{pmatrix}^T$ (and setting the velocity to zero), the acceleration of that point should be $x_{B,y}=z\cdot\ddot\theta$. Since $\theta$ has the same direction as the y-axis of the body (right-hand rule), the sign has to be positive. The point should be rotating in the positive direction around the x-axis.

However, this equation gives $x_{B,y}=-z\cdot\ddot\theta$, as if the point would rotate the other way around. Somewhere along the way I must have made an error or misinterpreted something, but I can't figure out where my mistake is. Perhaps someone can help me figure it out.

EDIT: 
Taking $\mathbf{x_B=R_x x_I}$ leads to correct computation of the acceleration. However, when I try to calculate the orientation of the gravity vector in the body frame with $\mathbf{x_B=R_x\begin{pmatrix}0&0&g\end{pmatrix}}^T$ the result is
$$\mathbf{g_B=\begin{pmatrix}0&-g\sin(\theta)&g\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}}^T,$$ when it should be $\mathbf{\begin{pmatrix}0&g\sin(\theta)&g\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}}^T$.

Comment: What would the result be if your starting matrix was transposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally think of rotation tensors as acting on vectors in the inertial frame and delivering vectors in the body frame. Hence, your starting relationship should be inverted: ${\bf x}_B = {\bf R} {\bf x}_I$.

Consider the following figure of the pendulum in its reference configuration and its current configuration:
[image]

If ${\bf X}$ is the vector from the origin to the tip of the pendulum in its reference configuration, ${\bf X} = -\ell {\bf E}_z$, then ${\bf x} = -\ell {\bf e}_z$ is that same material line in the current configuration. These are *different* vectors. ${\bf R}$ delivers the current from the reference: ${\bf x} = {\bf R} {\bf X}$. We also have ${\bf e}_y = {\bf R} {\bf E}_y$ and ${\bf e}_z = {\bf R} {\bf E}_z$, as well as ${\bf e}_x = {\bf R} {\bf E}_x$.

Now, *if ${\bf e}_y$ and ${\bf e}_z$ are represented in the inertial frame*, then they look like ${\bf e}_y = \cos \theta {\bf E}_y + \sin \theta {\bf E}_z$ and ${\bf e}_z = \cos \theta {\bf E}_z - \sin \theta {\bf E}_y$. We also have ${\bf e}_x = {\bf E}_x$. Hence, the components of ${\bf x} = x_X {\bf E}_X + x_Y {\bf E}_Y + x_Z {\bf E}_Z$ *as expressed in the inertial frame* transform according to

$\begin{bmatrix} x_X \\ x_Y \\ x_Z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ 0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_x \\ x_y \\ x_z \end{bmatrix}$,

where ${\bf x} = x_x {\bf e}_x + x_y {\bf e}_y + x_z {\bf e}_z$ is ${\bf x}$ expressed in the non-inertial frame.

Now, ${\bf g} = g {\bf E}_z$ always. It does not get rotated. We have ${\bf E}_z = \cos \theta {\bf e}_z + \sin \theta {\bf e}_y$. Notice that this is the opposite transform as before when we went from non-inertial to inertial. Therefore, the components of ${\bf g}$ will transform like

$\begin{bmatrix} g_x \\ g_y \\ g_z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ 0 & -\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} g_X \\ g_Y \\ g_Z \end{bmatrix}$

where we go from inertial to non-inertial components *of the same vector*.

Notice that ${\bf g} = g {\bf E}_z = g {\bf R}^T {\bf e}_z$.

Edit: This will give you something to think about but I realize that I did not relate the components of ${\bf X}$ to the components of ${\bf x}$ as you probably want to see. I will have to come back to this later as I am busy now.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed this way the acceleration is computed correct. However, the gravitation vector in the body frame seems to be off (see my edit).

Comment: There are subtle differences in the utility of your rotation matrix. The way I previously described it, I thought of ${\bf R}$ as an *operator* which rotates your pendulum from its reference position into its current position. This perspective takes reference configuration vectors and *delivers new vectors*. In contrast, you gave me the gravity vector, which is not to be operated on, but simply expressed in a different frame. In that case, the matrix you used needs to be transposed and the new perspective is that I simply have a change of coordinates/basis that I want to describe the *same*...

Comment: vector on. The gravity vector is not meant to be rotated. The pendulum is. You originally described the vectors as "frames." Maybe you can be a little clearer. Does ${\bf x_B}$ represent a geometric vector to be rotated into a new vector, or does it represent a 3X1 array of coordinates of some vector in some frame, where I can describe that same vector on another frame?

Comment: I imagined $\mathbf{x_B}$ as a vector in a coordinate system which rotates with the pendulum (body) and $\mathbf{x_I}$ as stationary. I see what you are trying to say, but it's still not clear to me. If the body rotates, I have to rotate a vector, which is defined in the intertial coordinate system, as well. It's difficult to grasp. Can you perhaps explain mathematically why I have to take $\mathbf{R^T}$ for the calculation of the gravity vector in the body CS?

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: For the second paragraph of the edit: I agree on the equations $\mathbf{e_y}=\cosθ\mathbf{E_y}+\sinθ\mathbf{E_z}$  and $\mathbf{e_z}=\cosθ\mathbf{E_z}−\sinθ\mathbf{E_y}$. But wouldn't that be $$\begin{pmatrix}e_x\\e_y\\e_z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\0&-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}E_x\\E_y\\E_z\end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: Yes! That is also true. Notice that my matrices all act on scalars: I listed a 3 by 1 array of scalars, whereas you listed a 3 by 1 array of geometric vectors. The question is: which of all these options do you mean ${\bf R}$ to represent? There is another option, which is getting the components of ${\bf x}$ from components of ${\bf X}$ which I haven't yet discussed. 

To take it to the next level, ${\bf R}$ is typically not meant to represent a matrix, but a tensor. Are you familiar with tensors? You can formulate everything with matrices as well, but the point is you need to be very clear

Comment: about what basis you are using to express each object.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $$\boldsymbol{x}_I = \mathbf{R}_x \boldsymbol{x}_B \tag{1}$$ and differentiating is the way to go.

Here $\boldsymbol{x}_B = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ \ell}$ is the position of the mass on the rotating frame, and its derivative is zero. Lets put (1) in a vector-matrix form

$$ \pmatrix{ x_I \\ y_I \\ z_I } = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ 0 &  \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ \ell} = \pmatrix{0 \\ -\ell \sin \theta \\  \ell \cos \theta}   $$

Taking the derivative of the above, you must note that $$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d} t}\mathbf{R}  = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{R} $$ for any rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ and $\times$ above is the vector cross product. There is two way to compute the above, one is to recognize that the columns of $\mathbf{R}$ are the direction vectors $\boldsymbol{\hat{i}}$, $\boldsymbol{\hat{j}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}$ of whatever coordinate frame it describes and thus

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{\hat{i}}  & \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{\hat{j}} & \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{\hat{k}} \end{bmatrix}$$ or my favorate way, which is to use the skew-symmetric cross product matrix and make it a matrix multiplication $$ \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{R} = [\boldsymbol{\omega}\times] \mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\ \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\ -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{R}$$

Now back to the derivatives of position. Use the chain rule and the product rule to get to the velocity vector

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_I = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{x}_I = \left( \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \mathbf{R}_x \right) \mathbf{R}_x \boldsymbol{x}_B  = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times (\mathbf{R}_x \boldsymbol{x}_B) = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{x}_I  \tag{2}$$

Here $\boldsymbol{\omega} = \pmatrix{\dot{\theta}\\0\\0} $ and the above can be expanded in matrix/vector form as follows

$$ \pmatrix{ \dot{x}_I \\ \dot{y}_I \\ \dot{z}_I } = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\dot{\theta} \\ \dot{\theta} & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ 0 &  \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ \ell} = \pmatrix{0 \\ -\ell \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \\ -\ell \dot{\theta} \sin \theta} $$

Finally, to get to the acceleration you repeat the derivative step, again using the chain rule

$$ \ddot{\boldsymbol{x}}_I = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_I = \dot{\boldsymbol{\omega}} \times \boldsymbol{x}_I + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \dot{ \boldsymbol{x}}_I = \dot{\boldsymbol{\omega}} \times \mathbf{R}_x \boldsymbol{x}_B + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \left( \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{R}_x \boldsymbol{x}_B \right)  \tag{3} $$

In matrix-vector form the above is

$$ \pmatrix{ \ddot{x}_I \\ \ddot{y}_I \\ \ddot{z}_I } = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\ddot{\theta} \\ \ddot{\theta} & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ -\ell \sin \theta \\  \ell \cos \theta}  + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\dot{\theta} \\ \dot{\theta} & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ -\ell \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \\ -\ell \dot{\theta} \sin \theta} \\ = \pmatrix{ 0 \\ \ell \dot{\theta}^2 \sin \theta - \ell \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta \\ -\ell \dot{\theta}^2 \cos \theta - \ell \ddot{\theta} \sin \theta} $$

To get local gravity, use $\mathbf{R}^\top$ as the $\mathbf{R}$ matrix is local to world as seen in (1).

$$  \boldsymbol{g}_B = \mathbf{R}_x^\top \boldsymbol{g}_I $$ or in matrix-vector form

$$ \boldsymbol{g}_B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ 0 &  -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ g} = \pmatrix{0 \\ g \sin \theta \\ g \cos \theta} $$